# py2app: Compiles app but app has error on opening

Tags: python-3.6, py2app

I am working on a Python application in Python3.6 that I would like to convert into a standalone application that can be ported easily to other devices. I tried using py2app as in [this tutorial](https://www.metachris.com/2015/11/create-standalone-mac-os-x-applications-with-python-and-py2app/).

Everything works well until I get to the point of actually creating the app. It does not throw any error in the creation process and creates the .app file, however, when I try to run it, A window pops up saying there is an error and gives me the options of terminating or opening the console. I tried opening the console but I cannot find any substantive information in the error messages.

These are the import statements that I have:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, build_opener
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import ssl
import urllib
import sys
import subprocess
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import webbrowser
from unidecode import unidecode
```

As far as I know the only 2 packages that aren't standard with python are bs4 and unidecode. My setup.py file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['GUImain.py']
DATA_FILES = ['logo.png']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
           'iconfile': 'logo.png',
           'includes': ['undidecode','bs4']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I haven't seen any other errors like this one from any of my searching. I have seen some suggestion that py2app doesn't fully support Python3.6. Does anyone know how I can figure out what error is being thrown? Any suggestions on different tools to use and tutorials on how to use them?

Comment: Have you tried `Show Contents` of `GUImain.app`? And browse to `GUImain/Content/MacOS/GUImain`. Running that will show the terminal.